# Is it possible to write a regular expression for finding a typical file matching pattern in config file(C#)

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible to write a regular expression for finding a typical file matching pattern.

e.g. File<13/04/2010>.txt should be picked up and not any other file.

i.e. Starting file name will be File followed by some dates and then the file extension.

If so, can we specify this pattern in the config file?

Looking for the solution in C#

Thanks

Comment: "the config file" is rather ambiguous. Besides, what has C# got to do with regular expressions? All regex implementations support such simple text strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match

```
@"File\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\.txt"
```

This matches `File` at first, then exactly two digits `\d{2}` followed by `/` ...
After the date, it matches a dot `\.` and the file-extension.

To match only files from april 2010 you can use something like `@"File\d{2}/04/2010\.txt"`

Comment: That will never match the < and >.

Comment: I thought the `<` and `>` exist to mark the date as an example. That's why I left them out intentionally ...

Comment: Can't use them as file name characters anyway (or / for that matter)

Comment: @Alex: yes you are right - @Thinking: `/` can not be used as a character for filenames - didn't realize this ...